# Can't use the camera

Tags: camera

I was following a tutorial on Youtube, everything went Ok until I reached the part where I had to set up my camera. It's just not working with me. Every time I click on Ctrl-Alt + 0 to add a camera the scene flips around and the main cube turns upside down for some reason leaving the other parts floating out. Also if I click on 0, to activate the camera view, it behaves the same way why is that?
https://media2.giphy.com/media/qE5DZycVR9Fir0Ev21/giphy.gif
https://media4.giphy.com/media/f5yWZd6a9qfWWjTOKi/giphy.gif

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Numpad 0 will not add a camera, it will align the camera to view.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you accidentally set some other object as your active camera (yes, believe it or not this is possible - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num 0</kbd> snaps the active camera to the view, whereas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num 0</kbd> re-assigns the active camera to whatever object you have selected - easy to mix up by mistake). To fix it, select your camera, and then make it the active camera again from the View menu or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num 0</kbd>. This should make it behave as normal again:

[image: CameraActive]